# How to trace TIME_WAIT sessions using tcpdump (or similar tool)

Tags: tcpdump, time-wait

I have a server with large number of TIME_WAIT sessions.
These are sessions that the server closed, but the client didn't close.

I want to analyze a sample session, to understand what happens there.
Simple "brute force" analysis of tcpdump output isn't productive, as most sessions are closed OK.

Is there a way to dig up only those connections that cause TIME_WAIT?

Comment: netstat -a will show you something. Guess you could try out wireshark. I don't actually see any point in you doing this, however.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of connections in the TIME_WAIT state means that your server is the initiator of their closing phase. It prevents against accepting late segments and ensures that the other end has correctly closed the connection.

It shouldn't be a problem to have a lot of them in most cases, it depends on the services that the server provides.
The main issue with a high number of TIME_WAIT connections is the memory consumption, which is only about 10MB for 40 000 of them.

If you think it may cause harm in your specific case, you can use *ss* from iproute2 to see which tuples are the culprits:

```
$ ss -tan state time-wait
```

Then, with a tool such as *wireshark*, you can easily analyse the TCP flow corresponding to that tuple with a filter similar to:

```
tcp.port == <port> and ip.addr == <ip>
```

You can also use the feature "follow TCP stream" from wireshark that will show you every segment from that specific connection.